# SQLAlchemy connection via proxy

Tags: python, proxy, sqlalchemy

I need to connect to existing database from SQLAlchemy via proxy.

```
        self.DB = {
            'drivername': 'oracle',
            'host': url,
            'port': port,
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'database': dbname
        }
        _engine = create_engine(URL(**self.DB))

        self.connection = _engine.connect()
```

I'm getting:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

And I'm pretty sure I just need proxy because of my company policy. I couldn't find any tips in documentation how can I create connection via proxy.

Comment: I'm not a Oracle expert, so I am not familiar with proxying db connections. How do you connect to the database from another tool, for instance the sqlplus command line tool?

Comment: For instance - SQL Developer.

Comment: Ok. How do you specify the connection info in sql developer?

Comment: Are you able to connect using another tool?

Comment: @codeape I'm not longer able to reproduce this error as our servers infrastracture was changed and proxy is no longer needed. The think is that with SQL Developer or some other tool I can specify proxy if it's needed.